# Drools : Operator RHS is considered as String instead of List

Tags: java, drools, dsl

I have below drools file where i have overridden the inbuilt in operator with my own custom operator.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import com.sample.Item;
rule R when
    $server :  Item(itemNumber in ["123","456"])
then
    $server.setValid(true);
end
```

Item class has just two variables

```
Item.java :
String itemNumber 
Boolean valid
```

In custom InOperatorEvaluator class which extends the BaseEvaluator class of drools I have the following method.

```
@Override
public boolean evaluate(InternalWorkingMemory workingMemory, InternalReadAccessor extractor, InternalFactHandle factHandle, FieldValue value) {
   //value.getValue();
   //some more operation + return booelan result based on evalution.
}
```

**Now the problem is that in drools 6.2.0.Final the value.getValue() returned Arraylist object of size 2 with values 123 and 456, but after upgrading to drools 7.52.0.Final the value.getValue() returns the following string.
"["123","456"]"**

I have checked the [code](https://github.com/kiegroup/drools/blob/master/drools-core/src/main/java/org/drools/core/base/FieldFactory.java) and this was probably an issue which they corrected in version 7.

I can convert the string to arraylist by splitting and replacing the quotes and brackets but is there a way to make the right side of the operator ["123","456"] as a list instead of string from drools itself ?

Can we change the valueType so it wont be treated as a string?